# unable to install requirements.txt on new computer

Tags: python, django

After getting a new pc, with a different user name, I can't install the requirements.txt in my python project, which has now a new path to the project folder because of the new windows user.
I am developing a VS code.  The project has a virtual environment, venv, that loads without problem.
But when trying to load the requirement.txt I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\olduser\python\project\venv\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\newuser\Python\project\venv\Scripts\pip.exe" -m install -r requirements.txt': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Python and pip are correctly defined in the environmental variables, the problem is (I think) that it is looking the python location from the previous PC

Comment: I guess you copied the virtual environment directory to the new pc. Discard it, create a new virtual environment and try again

Comment: yes, you are correct, created a new environment,  but when I try  pip install -r requirements.txt nothing happens

Comment: @ShanavasM pip install -r requirements.txt not running, no error, I just get the prompt after trying the command

Comment: That is strange.